# Prove that a finitely-generated free module has a finite basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Say I have a module $M$ over a ring $R$ that is

$1.$ finitely-generated, i.e. $\exists$ finite $X \subset M$ such that $M = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Rx_{i}, x_{i}\in X$ (but $X$ is not necessarily free)

$2.$ free, i.e. $\exists$ a basis $Y \subset M$ a.k.a. $Y$ is free and generates M, (but $Y$ is not necessarily finite).

Now I want to show, that there exists a finite basis for $M$. For vector spaces, this would obviously be trivial, but for some  $R$-Modul, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Furthermore, is every minimal generating subset of $M$ a basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the $ \beta_i $ are a basis (of unknown cardinality $ \kappa $) for the free $ R $-module $ M $, and the $ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n $ are a finite generating set; then each $ x_i $ is a $ R $-linear combination of finitely many of the $ \beta_i $; thus we may choose a finite subset of the $ \beta_i $ whose span includes all of the $ x_i $. But then, the span is equal to $ M $, and thus this subset is the desired finite $ R $-basis for $ M $.

Comment: @ghthorpe Every element of a module can be written as the *finite* linear combination of any spanning set (and thus any basis). This is simply the definition of "spanning set".

Comment: (I was trying to rephrase the question, in case you were wondering.) Ah yes, I remember. That makes sense!

Comment: As an additional question: Is every minimal generating subset of $M$ a basis?

Comment: see my answer. it might help

Comment: @ghthorpe Minimal with respect to inclusion (no proper subset of it is a generating set), or minimal with respect to cardinality (there is *no* subset of $ M $ of strictly smaller cardinality which is also a basis)?

Comment: @Starfall minimal with respect to cardinality

Answer (score 0):

we have $M$ is free and hence it is projective. Since it is finitely generated it is a direct summand of module of finite rank say $R^n$. Suppose $M$ has a basis of cardinality $>$ $n$. Consider the inclusion map from $M$ to $R^n$. Then since this map is injective we have these elements are linearly independent in $R^n$, which is a contradiction. Since we can have at most n linearly independent elements. So we have $rank(M)$$\le$ $n$.

Comment: This is not true for a general $R$, one can have $R^{n} \cong R^{m}$ for $m \neq n$, so certainly it can happen that there is more then $n$ linearly independent elements in $R^{n}$.